# can't manage QuickReply in pimax/fb-messenger-php

Tags: php, facebook-chatbot

Trying to manage the quickreply with pimax/fb-messenger-php in php, and it doesn't work. My code is next:

```
`                       $one= array();
                        $one['content_type'] = 'text';
                        $one['title'] = 'one';
                        $one['payload'] = 'one';

                        $two= array();
                        $two['content_type'] = 'text';
                        $two['title'] = 'two';
                        $two['payload'] = 'two';

                        $res =  array($one, $two);
                       $bot->send(new QuickReply($message['sender']['id'], "Hi there!",$res)); `
```

could you help me with it?

Comment: Please provide more context code

Comment: thnx @ConstantinGALBENU, I didn't use "use pimax\Messages\QuickReply;" - that was a problem...